# How to deploy an iOS app made with delphi berlin to App store?

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, firemonkey

When i try to submit my iOS app made with delphi berlin using xcode 8.3.2 i receive this error:

> This build is using a beta version of Xcode and can’t be submitted.
>   Make sure you’re using the latest version of Xcode or the latest seed
>   release found in the TestFlight release notes.

How from delphi berlin i can upload an iOS app to the app store ? because as far as i know berlin support only xcode 8 ?

Comment: AFAIK versions of Xcode 8.3.1 and above are supported. However, latest 8 variant is the Xcode 8.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the work around.

Your info.plist must contain all the folllowing section (the values worked for me):

```
<key>DTPlatformName</key>
<string>iphoneos</string>
<key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
<string>12H141</string>
<key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
<string>6E35b</string>
<key>DTSDKBuild</key>
<string>12H141</string>
```

I thought I post this information to save others time.

Comment: How are you adding those lines to the info.plist file since it is regenerated with every build/deploy operation?